# Significant Wait Time in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to optimize a query and I can see there is significant wait time for several of its stages, adding up to almost two seconds of the query:
[image: Screenshot showing wait times]

I've checked Bigquery Monitoring and we're using on average 4 slots, which is far from the 2000 slots limit for on-demand pricing.

What could this be due? Is there a way to optimize these times?

The results of this query is used to update a realtime app with geolocation data... so I need something fast.

Comment: I believe you should start with showing us the query with relevant test data, maybe someone can help you further. BigQuery is slow compared to e.g. an optimized Postgres instance, and query times above a second is normal. BR

Comment: thanks @roar-s. I'd be happy to share, but how would the query itself and the data would be relevant, if most of the time it takes to process goes in the "Wait" phase, and not in the "Read", "Compute", nor "Write" phases?

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery automatically allots slots that depending on your query size and complexity of your query. For your reference you can visit the link here for more information about [slots](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots#:%7E:text=A%20BigQuery%20slot%20is%20a,a%20capacity%2Dbased%20pricing%20model.) usage.

Might be a helpful reference, Google has a documentation dedicated to optimisation of queries here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned, The peak slot usage my queries incur in is about 4 slots. So there doesn't seem to be a slot shortage...

Comment: Understood, You can check the best practices link i posted above for optimization other than that I would recommend to contact Google and let them investigate your project's logs or possible hitting a quota in one of your resources. https://cloud.google.com/contact